# How to Configure Height of Dynamic UITableViewCell Based on Multiple Views

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I am working on an application that pulls in data from a server and displays the data in a `UITableView`. The data is dynamic, pulling in items that come from social networks.

Currently, I am pulling in a profile picture, username, and social network handle. That data is being displayed in in a `UITableView` similar to the way that Tweetbot displays its data. Here is a reference of Tweetbot's Timeline:

[image: Screenshot of Tweetbot Timeline]

As you can see, in the topmost post, the body text contains four lines. In the second post, from me, the body text contains only one line. You also may notice that in my post, the cell's height does not shrink, causing the cell to clip the `UIImageView`. It appears that there is an equal amount of space from the top of the image to the top of the cell as there is from the bottom of the image to the bottom of the cell. But when there is multiple lines of text in the body, the cell's height increases.

I normally set the `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` properties of `UITableView` to allow for dynamic height by pinning the content, but I don't know how to configure Auto Layout to allow for dynamic cell heights based on multiple views.

One thought that I had for configuring this layout is to detect the height of the cell with the body text pinned to the bottom of cell, creating the dynamic height. Then, if the height of the cell is greater than the sum of the height of the image and the top constraint from the image to the cell multiplied by 2 (bottom and top spacing between image view and cell top and bottom), I would delete the constraint between the bottom of the body text and add the constraint to the bottom of the image and cell.

In short, if a cell contains only one line of text, how can I ensure that the cell respects the image's dimensions without clipping the image?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating two constraints; one between the bottom of the image and the bottom of the cell, and and another between the bottom of the label and the bottom of the cell.

I set the constraint between the image and cell to have a desired `constant` with a `relation of` `greaterThanOrEqual`, while the constraint between the label and cell has a desired `constant` and a `relation` of `equal`. By doing so, if the body text grows larger, then the `greaterThanOrEqual` will allow the constraint between the image and cell to grow but never allow it to become smaller than the desired `constant` and cause the cell to clip the content.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this because it sounds like your constraints aren't setup correctly (from your own answer to this SO question).

If your constraints are satisfied you will get dynamic height calculated for free as part of your setup.

Here's a quick example I made showcasing self-sizing `UITableViewCell`s:

https://github.com/runmad/SelfSizingUITableViewCellExample

And here's an example constraints for a cell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{

    let topView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    let bottomView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        contentView.addSubview(topView)
        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        contentView.addSubview(bottomView)
        bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    static func reuseIdentifier() -> String
    {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}
```

The key take-away (regardless of the number of subviews in the cell) is that the subview(s) in the cell, must be constrained to all edges of the cell, which allows it to resize according to the `intrinsicContentSize` of any view. And if you have multiple subviews, you must ensure the constraints are correct between the subviews.